# proper structuring of Python package - unable to use package after installation from github (works correctly when imported from parent directory)

Tags: python-2.7, import, package

I am working on a package and using github as my repository.

My package has the following directory structure:

```
pkg_name
-- pkg_name (directory)
------ algorithm (directory)
------ __init__.py
-- tests (directory)
-- LICENSE
-- README.md
-- setup.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py`:

```
import algorithm
```

Algorithm is a directory that has its own `__init__.py` along with a couple of files. If I work on the package locally, fire up IPython from inside the pkg_name directory, I can do

```
import pkg_name
```

and everything works fine.

If I however install the package from github using

```
pip install git+git://url_to_package_on_github
```

the installation works just fine but when I try to import the package I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named algorithm
```

The problem is, I thought I have been following a proper structure for a package all along (consulted various resources I was could find including Python docs and the Hitchiker's guide) and really can't wrap my head around what I am doing wrong... If anyone could please shed any light what the proper package structure should be that would be greatly appreciated! Many, many thanks!

The package I am struggling with can be found here:
https://github.com/dreamwalkerrr/mledu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue laid not with my package structure but with contents of `setup.py`.

Identifying the subpackage in a call to `setup()` in `setup.py` resolved the issue.

```
packages = ['pkg_name', 'pkg_name.algorithm'],
```